# Is there a way to change the compaction throughput via startup options in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, parameter, startup

We are currently running a Cassandra cluster in K8S containers as Stateful sets. We're considering exposing the config file but we would like to know if perhaps we can provide this value as a startup parameter.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a command-line option/system property to change the compaction throughput.

You could use `nodetool setcompactionthroughput` *after* Cassandra has started.